# Render lists using python Template string clases

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to use a `Template` string class starting from a list. I started with:

```
from string import Template
temp = Template('-* $item - \n')
items = ["alpha", "beta", "gama"]
subs = ''.join([temp.substitute(item) for item in items])
```

This fails because it needs a dictionary and not a list.

Results should be:

```
-* alpha -
-* beta -
-* gama -
```

Some limitations:

- I know it can be done using `append` but I want the flexibility of passing templates, and some of them are more complicated than the one in example
- Should work with both python2 and 3
- Ideally will be something more like jinja2 or django templates rendering, but unfortunately I can't add third-party packages, besides I need only variables and list replacements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`substitute` needs to know what the `$item` placeholder in the template should be replaced with, so either provide a mapping dictionary:

```
subs = ''.join([temp.substitute({'item': item}) for item in items])
```

Or, as @Rfroes87 mentioned in the comment, pass `item` as a kwarg:

```
subs = ''.join([temp.substitute(item=item) for item in items])
```

Comment: Could also use `kwargs` with `substitute`, simplifying it as `temp.substitute(item=item)`.

Comment: @Rfroes87 Thanks, will add it as an option

Answer (score 1):

Try string formatting instead of templates, it might even have the same back-engine

```
subs = ''.join(['-* %s - \n' % item for item in items])
```

Comment: Works in 2.7.5.